# JUnit NullPointerException error in Android's "Hello, Testing" tutorial

Tags: android, junit

I followed Android's [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html) tutorial verbatim, yet when I run it I receive an error with the following Failure Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.helloandroid.test.HelloAndroidTest.testText(HelloAndroidTest.java:72)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

The exception occurs in testText()'s single statement:

```
  public void testText() {
    assertEquals(resourceString,(String)mView.getText());
  }
```

I don't understand why I am receiving this null pointer exception since both `resourceString` and `mView` are initialized in `onCreate()`:

```
  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
      super.setUp();
      mActivity = this.getActivity();
      mView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.helloandroid.R.id.textview);
      resourceString = mActivity.getString(com.example.helloandroid.R.string.hello);
  }
```

What could explain this in such a simple app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: The [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html) tutorial is made for the [XML version](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#upgrading) of "Hello, Android", not for the second, [dynamically constructed](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#ui) version.

I fixed the problem by modifying [HelloAndroid](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)'s `onCreate()`:

```
  if (false) { // don't use main.xml layout
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello, Android");
    setContentView(tv);
  }
  else
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not positive but I think the way you are trying to cast as a String might be part of the problem. Try mView.getText().toString() instead of casting it how you are now.

```
public void testText() {
    assertEquals(resourceString,(String)mView.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix it adding the @UiThreadTest to the test, like this:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testText() {
  assertEquals(resourceString,(String)mView.getText());
}
```

I hope it helps.